# Bootstrap tab content display issue

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

Html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabs_list">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" role="tab" id="selections_tab" href="#selections_pane" data-toggle="tab">Selections</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" role="tab" id="report_tab" href="#report_tab_pane" data-toggle="tab">Report</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="tab_content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="selections_pane" role="tabpanel">

        <button id="submit_btn">Generate</button>
      </div>
      <div id="report_tab_pane" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").on('click', function(){
        $('#report_tab').removeClass('disabled');
        $("#report_tab").click();
  });
})
```

When the Reports tab is clicked, the content on the Reports tab shows below the content of the Selections Pane. How can i make this show at the top regardless of the content on the Selections pane?

Comment: `@quinzyamg` Is you want when clicked on `Report Tab` then display both content of 1st tab and 2nd tab so 1st tab content should be on top and 2nd tab content show bottom of 1st tab?

Comment: have you tried with `tab-content` class instead of `tab_content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one row to your JS:

```
$('#selections_pane').hide();
```

And if you need content of the first tab again:

```
$('#selections_tab').click(()=>{

    $('#selections_pane').show();
});

$('#report_tab').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) $('#selections_pane').hide();
});
```

```js
 $(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").on('click', function(){
        $('#report_tab').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#selections_pane').hide();
        $("#report_tab").tab('show');
    });

    $('#selections_tab').click(()=>{

        $('#selections_pane').show();
    });

    $('#report_tab').click(function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) $('#selections_pane').hide();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabs_list">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" role="tab" id="selections_tab" href="#selections_pane" data-toggle="tab">Selections</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" role="tab" id="report_tab" href="#report_tab_pane" data-toggle="tab">Report</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="tab_content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="selections_pane" role="tabpanel">
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span><br>
      <span>sfsdfsdfsdf</span>
      <button id="submit_btn">Generate</button>
      </div>
      <div id="report_tab_pane" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, but then clicking back on the Selections tab the content is missing, should i just then do a tab("show") if the Selections tab is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

please find this answer.. i think there is some issues with your html snippet..

```js
$(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").on('click', function(){
        $('#report_tab').removeClass('disabled');
        $("#report_tab").trigger('click');
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabs_list">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" role="tab" id="selections_tab" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Selections</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" role="tab" id="report_tab" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Report</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
  <div class="card p-4">
   <button id="submit_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-success w-25">click here</button>
  </div> 
        </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
   <div class="card p-4">
    <p>report comes here</p> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: never wrap such tab widgets inside card.. i think that is the reason for the mislignement

Comment: I actually got the example from the bootstrap site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/. There is an example of how you should put the nav inside a card.

Comment: okay.. anyway hope that u got solution from the above snippet

Answer (score 0):

<strike>instead of calling the `click()` function on `$("#report_tab")`, use the Bootstrap function `tab('show')`</strike>

```js
$(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").on('click', function(){
        $('#report-tab').removeClass('disabled');
        $("#report-tab").click();
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="tabs_list" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="selections-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#selections" role="tab" aria-controls="selections" aria-selected="true">Selections</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" id="report-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#report" role="tab" aria-controls="report" aria-selected="false">Report</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div class="card-body">
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="selections" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="selections-tab"><button id="submit_btn">Generate</button></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="report" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="report-tab">hello</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It still displays the "Hello" below where the button would have been, the more content you add on the first pane the lower the "Hello" gets.

Comment: I'd misunderstood your actual problem. I've edited the code snippet. Your issue is probably in your markup rather than your JS code.